# Bcrypt_elixir and Argon 2 not working even with C Compiler installed

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I use my Macbook M1 Pro to learn Elixir and Phoenix and I am trying to use `bcrypt_elixir` and/or `argon2` to encrypt passwords. When I try to use the `bcrypt` or `argon` on `iex -S mix` this error is shown in my terminal.

```
Bcrypt.Base.hash_password("hard to guess", Bcrypt.Base.gen_salt(12, true))
[error] Process #PID<0.610.0> raised an exception
** (RuntimeError) An error occurred when loading Bcrypt.
Make sure you have a C compiler and Erlang 20 installed.
If you are not using Erlang 20, either upgrade to Erlang 20 or
use version 0.12 of bcrypt_elixir.
See the Comeonin wiki for more information.

    (bcrypt_elixir 3.0.1) lib/bcrypt/base.ex:15: Bcrypt.Base.init/0
    (kernel 8.5.2) code_server.erl:1317: anonymous fn/1 in :code_server.handle_on_load/5
[warning] The on_load function for module Elixir.Bcrypt.Base returned:
{%RuntimeError{
   message: "An error occurred when loading Bcrypt.\nMake sure you have a C compiler and Erlang 20 installed.\nIf you are not using Erlang 20, either upgrade to Erlang 20 or\nuse version 0.12 of bcrypt_elixir.\nSee the Comeonin wiki for more information.\n"
 },
 [
   {Bcrypt.Base, :init, 0,
    [file: 'lib/bcrypt/base.ex', line: 15, error_info: %{...}]},
   {:code_server, :"-handle_on_load/5-fun-0-", 1,
    [file: 'code_server.erl', line: 1317]}
 ]}
```

To verify my C Compiler, I tried on terminal `gcc --version` and `make --version` and it's worked because I have C Compiler installed.

```
gcc --version
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
❯ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Has anyone had a similar error and how to solve it?

- I verified if I had the C Compiler installed using `gcc` and `make`.
- I tried to use two encrypt libraries but both give the same error.
  Below are my Elixir and Erlang version

```
elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:10:10] [ds:10:10:10] [async-threads:1] [jit] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.14.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely able to reproduce what you shared, but here are the steps I took to generate a BCrypt string. I am on an Apple M1 Pro as well running the following versions of Elixir/Erlang via ASDF:

```
elixir          1.14.2
erlang          24.2
```

1. Add `{:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 3.0"}` to `mix.exs` and then `mix deps.get`
2. `iex -S mix` to get into an `iex` session
3. Ran the command:

```
iex> Bcrypt.Base.hash_password("hard to guess", Bcrypt.Base.gen_salt(12, true))
"$2a$12$G.GZInaTWWDuwzdh1BoWQuQzLLEPL2puowK5/4wn7.DrQG1IszNDK"
```

I have the same `make` version as you, but I do have a more recent `gcc` version:

```
❯ gcc --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
(base)
```

Notice the `Target` is for an `arm64` chip, whereas your `gcc` target is for a `x86_64` chip -- that could cause problems.

Also, just for reference, I tried using `bcrypt` on Elixir 1.13, but I could not start the app at all -- that package seems to require different settings, but I'll leave that discussion to a question about it specifically.

Comment: That awesome, do you know how could I change `x86_64` to `arm64`?

Comment: I've been trying to figure that out myself: notice that we both have versions of `make` for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0, and that could be causing some problems too.